# Python Keyboard Library 'Argument 1 must be string not unicode' Error

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm writing a Python program that detects and presses keys, but the library returns TypeError when I import it.

I tried using pynput.keyboard as well, but it sent the same error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.press('a')
```

This code returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "igpay.py", line 2, in <module>
    import keyboard
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from. import _winkeyboard as _os_keyboard
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_winkeyboard.py", line 37, in <module>
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

Is it something wrong with the library, or is something wrong with my computer?